# Как словить эвент другого класса и передать из него объект?

Tags: java, javafx, listener, tab

Имеется контроллер `Addlist`. Он вызывается из главного окна и осуществляет добавление нового `Tab` в `TabPane` контроллера другого класса: `ManageLists`.
Как понять когда передать сам `tab` в другой контроллер и как это сделать?

Addlist:

```
btnCreateList.setOnAction(t -> {
   if (!tfdListName.getText().isEmpty()) {
       listName = tfdListName.getText();

       Tab tab = new Tab();
       tab.setText(listName);

       /* Как передать tab */
   } else {
       alertStart();
   }
});
```

ManageLists:

```
@FXML
TabPane tabPane; 

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) { 
    /* Как услышать изменение в Addlist и словить tab, передав его в tabPane */ 
}
```

Comment: Можно пробросить callback из класса ManageLists в класс Addlist и вызывать его при отлове соответствующего события.

Comment: Думаю это можно организовать через наблюдатель (Observer).[Например как здесь](http://www.javenue.info/post/76)